# Saving a dataframe result value to a string variable?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I created a dataframe in spark when find the max date I want to save it to the variable. Just trying to figure out how to get the result, which is a string, and save it to a variable.

code so far:

```
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(date) FROM account")
sqlDF.show()
```

what results look likes:

```
+--------------------+
| max(date)|
+--------------------+
|2018-04-19T14:11:...|
+--------------------+
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as max_

# get last partition from all deltas
alldeltas=sqlContext.read.json (alldeltasdir)
last_delta=alldeltas.agg(max_("ingest_date")).collect()[0][0]
```

last_delta will give you a value, in this sample the maximum value of the column ingest_date in the dataframe.

Comment: `Your_max_date = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(date) FROM account").collect()[0][0]`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're computing a global aggregate (where the output will have a single row) and are using PySpark, the following should work:

```
spark.sql("SELECT MAX(date) as maxDate FROM account").first()["maxDate"]
```

I believe this will return a `datetime` object but you can either convert that to a string in your driver code or do a `SELECT CAST(MAX(DATE) as string)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that sqlDF is a pandas dataframe and the value you want to get is at index 0:

```
max_date = str(sqlDF.get_value(0, 'max(date)'))
```

Comment: that doesn't work in spark. I got  sqlDF.first() to show the first row. but I just want the value.